# how to do a get and set method to allow reading of save files from different page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, save, isolatedstorage

How do i get the FileName and FileText1 from the other page? The codes on the Viewing Text Page says that the FileName and FileText1 doesn't exist in the current context.

This is the codes for the creating page to save the written text:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
{
    public partial class CreateQuizPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public CreateQuizPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private const string FileName = "Name";
        private const string FolderName = "QuestionFolder";
        private string FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, FileName);



        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.OnSaveFile(FilePath);


            MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully");

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CompleteQuizPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }



        private void OnSaveFile(string filePath)
        {
            StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));

            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && !myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                }

                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                    {

                        string someTextData = textFileName.Text + text1.Text;
                        writer.WriteLine(someTextData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

This is the codes for the viewing page to view the text:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
    {
        public partial class AnswerQuestionPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {

            public AnswerQuestionPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                }





            private void OnReadSelected(string filePath)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(filePath))
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                            {
                                this.titleText.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("File not found!");

                    }
                }
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {



                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CompleteAnswerPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                this.OnReadSelected(FileName);
                this.OnReadSelected(FileText1);
            }




        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two members are marked as private so can not be accessible from anywhere else (other than that class).

A better way of doing this is to create a static class for your constants and use it from all of your pages.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string FileName = "Name";
    public const string FolderName = "QuestionFolder";
}
```

and then call it like this from any of your pages:

```
            this.OnReadSelected(Constants.FileName);
            this.OnReadSelected(Constants.FileText1);
```

Comment: I'm getting errors like 'WindowsPhoneApp1.Model.Constants.FilesName is inaccessible due to its protection level' and 'WindowsPhoneApp1.Model.Constants does not contain a definition for FileText1.'

Comment: That's the error i'm getting, and i'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: sorry, changed it, (was a copy paste issue) ofcourse they need to be public.

Comment: ok, i get waht you mean. after changing it, i'm still getting the error 'WindowsPhoneApp1.Model.Constants does not contain a definition for FileText1.'.

Comment: Because you have to add another field there called "FileText1", currently only FileName and FolderName are defined there.

Comment: ok, after i've added that, they said there is no definitions for FileText1. FileText1 is the binding of a text for the text block control named text1.